# How to get url value in php. My url is https://www.website.com/search.php?search=dk%20&%20Boss

Tags: php, mysql

Anybody help me. In this url & symbol is there

code is
$url = $_GET['search'];

but i get only dk but i wanted dk & Boss

Comment: [Please read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), your question is vague, and shows lack of effort, people are likely to not help you. Have you read the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)?

Comment: And to point the issue, your URL is not what you expect, `&` is a special character

Answer (score 1):

$var = urlencode('dk & Boss');

https://www.website.com/search.php?search=$var;

$url = urldecode($_GET['search']);

Comment: thank you very much. My problem is solved